# DDD - how to rehydrate

Tags: domain-driven-design, aggregate, automapper

> **Question**: what is the best, efficient and future proof way to
>   rehydrate an aggregate from a repository? What are the pro's and con's of the provided ways and are my perceptions correct?

Let's say we have an Aggregate Root with private setters but public getters for accessing *state*

Behaviour is done through methods on the aggregate root.

A repository is instructed to **load** an aggregate.

At the moment I see a couple of possible ways to achieve this:

1. set the state through **reflection** (manual or automatic eg.
   Automapper)
2. make **constructors** that accept properties so state is set
3. load the aggregate with a **[state object](https://lostechies.com/gabrielschenker/2015/05/25/ddd-the-aggregate/)**

1) [Jimmy Bogard](https://lostechies.com/jimmybogard/2009/09/18/the-case-for-two-way-mapping-in-automapper/) alludes that his tool **Automapper** isn't meant for two-way mapping. But some people argue that we have to be pragmatic, use tools in a way it helps you.

For me, I don't like a *full* rehydration through reflection. Maybe Automapper ceise to exist or aggregate roots are bent in such a way the mapping can be done (see some comments of [Vaughn](https://vaughnvernon.co/?p=879) on his article).

2) creating **constructors** for rehydration, with a couple of parameters so the state of the aggregate is rehydrated in a correct way.

These couple of parameters can expand (= new constructors) or the definition can change. I like this approach, except the part of having a bunch of parameters.

3) the **state** is a property of the aggregate root. The state is encapsulated in a new object and this object is build by the repository and is then given to the aggregate root for proper init.

Some people argue that building this state object is *more* work (new class, exposure of state properties on entity and aggregate root to enforce business rules), but it provides a clean way to initiliaze the state.

Say that we need event sourcing, does the loading of a state resemble in loading events? And does the state object provide a way of handling events? Is it more future proof?

Comment: Does your definition of "future proof" somehow rule out ORMs, or do you include them in "reflection"? Because that's how many people rehydrate their entities right now.

Comment: I agree with @Joseph: the domain is the truth and is not mutable through reflection, so we'd rather use constructors or states to rehydrate an aggregate.

Comment: "Is not mutable through reflection" - everything is mutable through reflection :) Also, you don't really answer my question.

Comment: @guillaume31: we have repositories for the future proof thingy. If we want to use dapper, ado.net or some other way to map to a data store, we could fix it in the concrete repository implementation. But we don't like the idea of setting state through reflection :)

Comment: You might have to explain exactly what you mean by "future proof" (is it about the next trendy approaches or the maintainability of your code?), but I get your point. There's no ideal solution though, since altering your constructors to suit a rehydration scenario will also probably broaden the mis-usability surface of your domain layer.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I would argue that trying to future-proof too much represents a trap that many people fall into that adds undue complexity to a codebase. There is a fine balancing act between sound architectural decisions and over-architecting a solution to problem that is not guaranteed to exist.

That being said, I fully agree with what Jimmy says, in regards to AutoMapper not being intended for two-way mapping.  Your domain represents the "truth" in your application, and should not be directly mutable.  I have worked on projects with two-way mappings, and while they do work, there is a tendency to start treating the domain objects as nothing more than DTOs.  It becomes painful when you start having read-only properties, having to reflect to do your setting - tooling or not.  From a DDD perspective, we should not be allowing for outside influences to simply say what a property value should be, because it will lead to an anemic domain model over time, most likely.

Internal states do work well, but they are at the cost of additional overhead and complexity.  There is a legitimate trade-off, as you mention, in that you are adding a fair amount of work.  However, you can use that opportunity to allow the aggregate to validate the state against the self-contained business rules within the aggregate, prior to allowing the state to be set.  That addresses the largest concern that I have with two-way mapping.  You can at least enforce that a state object contains valid data and then only construct the aggregate if it is valid.  It is more testable, as well.  The largest problem that I have seen with this approach is that the skill level of your team will have a direct bearing on the success of this being utilized correctly.  It could be argued that the complexity does not add enough value to implement domain-wide, as you will likely have aggregates that have different levels of churn.  A couple of projects that I have been involved in have used this approach, and I found little advantage over straight constructor usage.

Normally, I use constructors for rehydration in most cases.  It walks the line between not being overly-complex, plus it leaves responsibility for the aggregate to allow or disallow the construction of the object - again, allowing for the domain to be in control of whether the hydration attempt would result in a valid object.  A good compromise to constructor bloat is the use a mutable DTO as a parameter for the constructor, essentially acting as a data structure to maintain a consistent constructor signature over time.  In that essence, it is also somewhat future-proof.  It takes the most attractive perk of the state object approach, which is the clean signatures, but removes the additional layer of an internal abstraction.

You mention event sourcing as a possibility down the road.  State loading is not very similar to what you would be doing, at all (in my opinion).  With a state object, you are snapshotting the state of the aggregate at a given point in time.  With event sourcing, you will be replaying events, each of which represents the data required to mutate the state, as opposed to the state, itself.  As such, your constructor will likely be a collection of events, representing a chain of deltas to mutate the state repeatedly, until it reaches the current state.  When you want to hydrate your aggregate, you will supply it with the events that are related to that aggregate, and it will replay them to get to the current state.  This is one of the true strengths of event sourcing, as well.  You are forcing the hydration of your domain objects to go through the business logic required to create them, each time.  Given a list of events, the aggregate will enforce that each state change is valid by applying the event in a consistent fashion, whether the event is being applied in real-time, or replayed to get to the current state.

Back to the future-proof aspect, as it relates to event sourcing, there is a conscious effort required when events require change.  Since you have to replay an event to get to the current state, you will very likely have to deprecate events and bring up new events to transition to as your business logic changes.  You may (read as "likely will") find yourself versioning events.  Not only does your aggregate need to understand current state change requirements, but it also needs to understand previous state change requirements.  So, if you change an event handler, you will have to ensure that it will be valid for existing events, as well.  When you are adding additional data to an event, it is usually not too involved.  But when you start removing data from an event signature, you instantly make that event at risk for being incompatible with earlier structures.  Likewise, even changing the names of the data structures inside of an event can cause backwards compatibility issues.  If you start event sourcing, you do not need to worry as much about future-proofing as you do backwards compatibility.  Event sourcing is great, but be prepared for additional complexity.

Comment: We're building the model in the given three ways (Proof of Concept). Your answer helps a lot, thanks.